# How to access documentation in javascript

Tags: javascript, python

Is it possible to access the documentation in the javascript at runtime as we do in python like

```
object__doc__
```

I am just looking for an easy way to discover about inbuilt functions rather then googling for them all the time.
Also is there something equivalent to python's `dir(object)` , again I am looking for it because i don't know how to discover about what properties / functions an object exposes.

Answer (score 2):

No, JavaScript doesn't have that.

You can however write comments in a consistent way and parse the source code to generate documentation.

> Also is there something equivalent to python's dir(object)?

Not in JavaScript, but browsers generally have a `console.dir()` which performs a similar thing.

Comment: One could also parse functions source code at runtime (via `.toString()`).

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, there is not javascript equivalent of python's `dir(object)`. Though if you're looking for a documentation generator, check out [PDoc](http://pdoc.org/). Otherwise, if you're looking for documentation about javascript, the [Mozilla Developer Network's Javascript Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference) is an excellent resource.

Comment: I think this is the perfect answer would you mind adding a bit about dir(object) functionality as well ? sorry for adding that part late